# Why is $\{1+2x-x^2,4-2x+x^2,-1+18x-9x^2\}$ not a basis on $\Bbb P_2(\Bbb R)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Why is $\{1+2x-x^2,4-2x+x^2,-1+18x-9x^2\}$ not a basis on $\Bbb P_2(\Bbb R)$? The set contains three vectors, and they do not appear to be linearly dependent of each other,

Comment: In a $n$  ($n<\infty$) dimensional vector space, a set of $n$ vectors forming a matrix of nonzero determinant is equivalent to the set begin a basis. See if you can prove that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As vectors, we have the following set: $\{(1,2,-1),(4,-2,1),(-1,18,-9)\}$. Placing them in a matrix and taking a reduced row echelon form, we get that this matrix has rank 2 and thus cannot span the space. We can also see that by noting that $7(1,2,-1)  -2(4,-2,1) = (-1,18,-9)$.

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=determinant&a=*C.determinant-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%7B%7B1%2C2%2C-1%7D%2C%7B4%2C-2%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C18%2C-9%7D%7D&f=Determinant.detmatrix_%7B%7B1%2C2%2C-1%7D%2C%7B4%2C-2%2C1%7D%2C%7B-1%2C18%2C-9%7D%7D) says they are dependent.